# How do I make my bot remove/delete roles in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def removerole(ctx, *, role: discord.Role = None):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator and role:
        guild = ctx.guild
        await guild.delete_role(role.guild, name=role)
        await ctx.send(f"""{ctx.author.mention} The role has been deleted""")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"""Sorry {ctx.author.mention}, you either don't have the administrator permissions or you misspelled or did not include the name of the role you would like to remove.""")
```

This is the current code I have for a removerole command. I've either done my code wrong or maybe delete_role has been removed in the latest version of discord.py rewrite because I'm getting this error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'delete_role'
```

I hope someone will be able to help me :>

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=delete_role

`delete_role` has never been part of discord.py rewrite (>= 1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild) has no `delete_role` function. Here is one way of doing it:

```py
@client.command()
async def removerole(ctx, *, role: discord.Role = None):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator and role:
        guild = ctx.guild
        if role in guild.roles: # Check if role is in the guild
            await role.delete()
            await ctx.send(f"""{ctx.author.mention} The role has been deleted""")
            return

    await ctx.send(f"""Sorry {ctx.author.mention}, you either don't have the administrator permissions or you misspelled or did not include the name of the role you would like to remove.""")
```

Comment: I love this community so much, thank you for the quick response. :DD